# AWS Cognito Google login overwrites mapped attribute values in user pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, google-signin, aws-amplify

Question specific to SocialIDP (google signin):
I give my users the option to change their 'preferred_username'. When they do, the preferred_username attribute is updated in my cognito user pool.
However, when they sign in again (google signin), Cognito does not keep the value it has stored in the pool for 'preferred_username'. It gets overwritten by whatever Google has for that mapped attribute.
Can anyone help? Here's my function that updates the user pool attributes

```
export const updateCognitoUserAttributes = async (user, attributes) => {
return await Auth.updateUserAttributes(user, {
    ...attributes.appSpecificCode
    ? { 'custom:appSpecificCode': attributes.appSpecificCode}
    : { 'email': attributes.email,
        'family_name': attributes.family_name,
        'given_name': attributes.given_name,
        'preferred_username': attributes.preferred_username
    }
})
    .then(res => {
        return res;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return err;
    });
}
```

Here are 3 pics showing preferred_username before change, after change, and then after I log out and log back in, notice it's changed back to what it was before. I can see why this would happen give that it is mapped to Google's "name" attribute, but the amplify docs indicate this value is changeable (and is in fact, as shown, changed in the pool), but that change should be permanent? What's the point in allowing these attributes to be changed if they just get overwritten every time a user logs in? (it's not just preferred_username that gets overwritten. Any attribute that is mapped to a google attribute gets overwritten). Any help appreciated.

[Before change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blidy.png)

[After change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcbvv.png)

[After logout/login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNA5d.png)

Comment: I haven't really faced this scenerio before, but I would try to see if I can use a pre/post authetication lambda trigger as a dirty fix.

Comment: Essentially I just put in a check whether the user is Social IdP or regular cognito, and if the former go to our DB to get the preferred_username (as we're also keeping user data beyond what we get from cognito), and not even bother updating the cognito user pool with any edited attributes for Social IDP.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's nothing that can be done. Just found this same issue on the amplify github. In short, from amplify documentation:

> Amazon Cognito must be able to update your mapped user pool attributes when users sign in to your application. When a user signs in through an identity provider, Amazon Cognito updates the mapped attributes with the latest information from the identity provider. Amazon Cognito updates each mapped attribute, even if its current value already matches the latest information. If Amazon Cognito can't update the attribute, it throws an error. To ensure that Amazon Cognito can update the attributes, check the following requirements:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-specifying-attribute-mapping.html.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/7300

sigh.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot turn the overwriting off.

However, you can set up an attribute mapping of Google's `preferred_username` to a custom Cognito attribute like `custom:preferred_username`.

Then update Cognito's `preferred_username` using `custom:preferred_username` in your application code, **but only if `preferred_username` is not set yet**.

`custom:preferred_username` will be overwritten on each login, but after the first login you will ignore it.